# "window-combination-resize" sometimes not working

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda, microsoft-windows

In my `.emacs` I use

```el
(setq window-combination-resize nil)
```

to prevent Emacs from resizing split windows evenly.

In the upper part of the buffer I usually have an Org mode file, in the bottom part is the agenda view. I chose to have the agenda view much smaller than the Org-mode above.

On my GNU/Linux machine (Emacs 26.3), when rebuilding the agenda view with `r`, the uneven split size is kept. That's how it should be.

On the Windows machine in the office (Emacs 27.2), when rebuilding the agenda view with `r`, the split windows are always resized evenly. Seems like Emacs ignores my configuration.

Am I doing something wrong or is `(setq window-combination-resize nil)` ignored in the builds for Windows?

Comment: `nil` should be the default value for this variable, so you should not even have to set it in your `.emacs`. Nevertheless, check the value on Windows with `C-h v window-combination-resize` - it might be that somehow it is not set properly.

Comment: You are right, thank you! Seems like I messed up some other things in the `.emacs`. I recreated it from scratch and decided to use `org-agenda-window-frame-fractions` instead to get the desired smaller agenda view.